# I burnt a resistor from the output of a crystal oscillator and am confused why

Tags: clock, crystal

I have this 40 MHz crystal clock connected to [this](https://lsicsi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/LS7366R.pdf) IC. QC_FCK0->FCK0 and QC_FCK1->FCK1. Resistors are 1 M Ohm and capacitors are 18 pF. I am not used to dealing with clocks, and am confused why resistor 13 burned out when powering with 5 volts.

[image: My clock schematic]

Comment: There's no reason it will burn based on the information provided.

Comment: Why would you even power R13 with 5V? That makes no sense, neither the circuit with two 1 megaohm resistors connected in series with a crystal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way could a 1MΩ resistor burn out in a 5V circuit. You could have physically damaged it. Also, in no way will that oscillator function with 1MΩ series resistors.

If you look carefully at the datasheet, a 1MΩ resistor is required *across* the crystal to bias the amplifier on the chip, and no series resistors are called for.

[image]

In the event series resistors were used (say to reduce the drive level) they would be lower in value by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: thank you. I must have damaged it during soldering, or it shorted out.